# Laravel Composer Installation “shell menus” Option Missing

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have downloaded Composer-Setup.exe. from https://getcomposer.org. I am installing composer but "Shell Menu" option not found during installation. Composer was installed successfully but i am unable to "use composer here" as i used my previous project.

opreating system: Windows 7

XAMPP Install in D drive

Thanks in advance

Comment: in cmd run composer -v and see what results you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The feature was completely removed in the new update

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5169

Answer (score -1):

Composer doesn't give you shell. Please try with cmd in windows. Press windows+R from your key board or open run and type cmd then try. And you can also use with git bash

Comment: Yes, it can. I first install Composer way back in 2015 and it has shell menus. Yesterday, I install composer in my computer at the office and it doesn't have option for shell menu in the installation setup.